# Conditional formatting of a field on a sharepoint list by month of a date

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

As you can see in the picture, I have a date type field and I would like this field only to be displayed in orange when the month of the date is equal to the month of the current date but I don't not see how to do it.

Anyone have any idea for this?

[image: =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either of below JSON codes on your date column as per your requirements:

**Based on Month only**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(getMonth(@currentField) == getMonth(@now), 'Orange', 'initial')",
    "padding-left": "10px"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Based on Month & Year**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(getMonth(@currentField) == getMonth(@now) && getYear(@currentField) == getYear(@now), 'Orange', 'initial')",
    "padding-left": "10px"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

Make sure you are adding this JSON on correct date & time column.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Update**:

Follow below steps to add JSON code to column formatting:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on column header/name
3. Select **Column settings** & then **Format this column**

   [image]
4. Make sure your date column is selected under **Choose Column** dropdown
5. Add JSON at the last textbox on right side panel (**Advanced mode**)
6. Click **Save**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(getMonth([$DateField])==getMonth(@now), 'Orange', '')",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

More info on JSON column formatting can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

[image]

Comment: it does not work..

Comment: Have you updated [$DateField] to your field name? Or to @currentField?